Is this wall between kitchen and living room load bearing
There’s a wall in my house that sits in the middle, running parallel to the floor and ceiling trusses. Is it load bearing?



——
Adding more photos. There is a 2x6 going through trusses. Here are the photos of it taken at different directions.





——
Zoom in to the corner. The corner is a bit complex because it’s a tripod shape. Most of the studs in this corner are 2x4s except for one 2x6 tucked in the middle, and I think, it’s because that 2x6 is the end stud of the wall frame.





Some clues say it's not structural.  The truss direction as you say.  And the ducts hint that the wall is there only to hide them.  But you can't just guess.  You've got so much of the wall and ceiling removed, why not remove a little more so you can see what the wall is doing above it?  Or maybe you can already see above this wall by viewing from the space in the next joist bay over, where the two white cables go up.

Thank you so much. I added some photos taken over the ceiling. There’s a long 2x6 sitting through the bottom of all trusses. Not sure if it’s really all trusses cause it seems to be blocked by some wood sheets near a return vent. Is it critical?

It looks like a partition wall. Not load bearing.  The 2x4s above the wall look to be there to anchor the wall to rather than the wall supporting anything.  The questionable area is the corner.

Thanks, @RMDman. the corner does look complex. I added a few more photos. I looked at those studs in that corner, they all have the function of attaching drywall sheets, not sure if they have structural function too. Is there a way I can better check the corner?

Yes, the other post was very helpful. I was wondering if I can get an answer for  my particular case. It seems to hit the mark of non load bearing signs but the connected corner and doorway make me feel unsure.

That other post (and many more like it on this site) all suggest that no, you cannot get an answer. No one can say with confidence through a small hole in the internet that you are free to cut away parts of your home. If you want that level of confidence, get a local expert to look.
